# Eclipse Menu Disappeared (another one)

Tags: java, menu, eclipse, ide

I encountered the (most likely) same strange behaviour as another user, but I'm quite certain, it has something to do with an update to Ubuntu itself within the last week or two.

What have I done? - Used Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) within 11.10 for month, the menu showed up - as predicted - as a seperate menu, not a global one - My own RCP application is successfully showing a global menu.

An update occured... - The menu vanished. Neither UBUNTU_MENUPROXY nor APPMENU_DISPLAY_BOTH is helping - Even tried [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/eclipse/+bug/618587/comments/46) - but to no avail

So until now the information I can provide is not very helpful, but starting Eclispe from console and watching the start of my own applications, I've recognized some new DEBUG messages:

```
** Message: a new manager occured at org.globalmenu.manager, :1.6
** (Eclipse:16040): DEBUG: gtk-menubar-gtk2.vala:25: map called
```

By the way: My own Eclipse RCP applications, still working perfectly (ok, as good as I've programmed them and that might be far from perfect).`

The following lines also appear during the startup of my app

```
** Message: a new manager occured at org.globalmenu.manager, :1.6
** (SWT:21632): DEBUG: gtk-menubar-gtk2.vala:25: map called
** (SWT:21632): DEBUG: gtk-menubar-gtk2.vala:25: map called
```

but they don't seem to have any negative effect. There is also a syserr call on exiting the RCP app:

```
(SWT:21632): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
```

but this is "old news" and I never encountered any sideeffects with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny... Answering ones own question seems a bit schizophrenic, but - whatever!

I found
1) the reason and so, of course
2) the solution to this problem.

The problem was, that I used a PPA from launchpad with a couple of Gnome-Shell extensions. I wanted to try, if those coul make the new shell more "sexy" for me. Doesn't change a thing, though - at leats for me. From that repository I'd installed a gnome shell global menu extension.
It wasn't active, but after it's installation I found the Eclipse menu at once, where it belongs to.

Hope, that if someone else runs into this kind of problems, that this helps to solve it...