# Android Developer Tools (ADT) installation gives GTK errors when not run as sudo

Tags: installation, android, eclipse

I installed the Android Developer Tools (ADT) bundle, which includes the Eclipse platform, using the [official instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html). When I run the program from the command line I see this message 8 times:

> LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

When I exit I get:

`>(ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion 'GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed`

`>(ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion 'GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed`

`>(ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion`GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed`

`>(ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion 'GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed`

`>(ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion 'GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed`

`>(ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.`

`>(ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion 'GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed`

`>(ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion 'GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed`

What is going wrong? 
and
Should I expect ADT to work normally, or with some errors, or with reduced functionality?

**UPDATE**

When running as `sudo`:

> sudo adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/eclipse/eclipse

there are no GTK errors. How can I run ADT/Eclipse without `sudo` and without running into the GTK errors?

Comment: Have you tried running it as `sudo`? Also is your OS 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @lordqwerty 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: @lordqwerty running it as `sudo` give me no GTK errors. Any ideas on how to avoid the errors without sudo?

Comment: not sure entirely. I'll post an answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for this is because you're running 64-bit architecture. This can hopefully be fixed quite easy. When running android on 64-bit Ubuntu you need 32-bit libs. This can be easily installed by running the following in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Give that a go. If it works without using `sudo` and your above edit, then happy days! If not I'll take a look around. This fixed issues I had on my 64-bit ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and download the ADT zip and use it for installation. If  you face any problem then let me know.

Comment: I used that file to install already.

Answer (score 0):

Someone having the [same issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/108146/49587) found that it was related to some PPAs they'd added for access to some GNOME Shell extensions.

Unless it was a standard installation, check if any additional PPAs were added and test for the while using a different [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment#Gallery).